# Python unittest: Accessing decorated test attributes in setUp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-unittest

I'm trying to figure out how to decorate a test function in a way that makes the information from the decorator available to setUp. The code looks something like this:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        stopService()
        eraseAllPreferences()
        setTestPreferences()
        startService()

    @setPreference("abc", 5)
    def testPreference1(self):
        pass

    @setPreference("xyz", 5)
    def testPreference2(self):
        pass
```

The goal is for setUp to understand it's running `testPreference1` and to know that it needs to set preference "abc" to 5 before starting the service (& similarly regarding "xyz" and testPreference2).

I can of course just use a conditional on the the test name (`if self._testMethodName == "testPreference1"`) but that doesn't feel quite as maintainable as the number of tests grows (+ refactoring is more error-prone). I'm hoping to solve this in `setUp` rather than overriding the `run` implementation. I'm also having

I'm running python3.6 although if there are creative solutions depending on newer python features happy to learn about that too.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators work well but there's no real "official" way to get the underlying method so I just did what the unittest source does: `method = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)`

```
import functools
import unittest

def setFoo(value):
    def inner(func):
        print(f"Changing foo for function {func}")
        func.foo = value

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return inner

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        method = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
        print(f"Foo = {method.foo}")

    @setFoo("abc")
    def testFoo(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.testFoo.foo, "abc")

    @setFoo("xyz")
    def testBar(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.testBar.foo, "xyz")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```